# How do I change the zAxis of a Paper from MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello I want to know how do you change the zAxis of a paper from MUI

[image]

As you can see the carousel overlaps my menu and I would like my menu to be on top of everything.

This is how I have it wrapped:

```
<Box sx={{ background: '#272A31', flexGrow: 0, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
          <StyledIconButton size="small" edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu" sx={{ mr: 2 }} onClick={handleToggle} ref={anchorRef} >
              <GamesIcon />
              <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}> GAMES </Typography>
              <Popper open={open}  anchorEl={anchorRef.current} role={undefined} placement="bottom-start" transition disablePortal > 
              {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
                 <Grow {...TransitionProps}
                    style={{
                      transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom-start' ? 'left top' : 'left bottom',
                  }}
                >
                  <StyledPaper sx = {{zIndex: 1600}} >
                    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                      <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="composition-menu" aria-labelledby="composition-button" onKeyDown={handleListKeyDown}> 
                      <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>JUNGLE RAIDER</StyledMenuItem>
                      <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>MEGAMAN TEMPLATE</StyledMenuItem>
                      <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>TOWER DEFENSE</StyledMenuItem>
                      <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>BLADES AND DUNGEON</StyledMenuItem>
                      <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>FIXSPACE</StyledMenuItem>
                    </MenuList>
                  </ClickAwayListener>
              </StyledPaper>
            </Grow>
          )}
       </Popper>
    </StyledIconButton>
 </Box>
```

While my Carousel is wraped in the following way:

```
<Box mb = {2} mt = {2} sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: -1}}>
      <Card sx={{ width: 1500, backgroundColor: "transparent"}} >
          <Carousel fullHeightHover={false} navButtonsAlwaysVisible={true} duration={500} animation="slide" 
             navButtonsProps={{
                 style: {
                     backgroundColor: '#FF5917',
                     borderRadius: 0,
                }
            }} >
                {items.map( (item, i) => <Item key={i} item={item} />)}
          </Carousel>
      </Card>
    </Box>
```

Even though the paper is at z-(1600) and the carousel box at z-(-1) it still overlaps the paper for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mui.com/customization/z-index/ check this link. tooptip has highest zindex value. you can add it to your popper

Comment: I have try adding it to the popper, paper and so far hasn't work.

Comment: By just adding zIndex: 2 to the Box worked, but not in the popper/paper or anything else.